# How to rename XML attributes from Java classes using JAXB annotations?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have this class defintion:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class RssRoot {

private String _version;

private String _xmlns_content;

@XmlAttribute()
public String get_version() {
    return _version;
}

@XmlAttribute()
public String get_xmlns_content() {
    return _xmlns_content;
}

public void set_version(String version) {
  _version = version;
 }

 public void set_xmlns_content(String xmlnsContent) {
  _xmlns_content = xmlnsContent;
 }

 public RssRoot() {
  super();

  this._version = "2.0";
  this._xmlns_content = "http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/";
 }

}
```

And it generates this xml:

```
<rssRoot xmlnsContent="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/" version="2.0"/>
```

However, I need to rename `xmlnsContent` to `xmlns:content`, and `rssRoot`, to `rss`. How can I do this?

I tried with `@XmlAttribute(name = "xmlns:content")` above the getter and near to the property declaration, but no luck. The thing fails with this message:

> Root Exception stack trace:
>       com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of IllegalAnno
>       tationExceptions
>       Class has two properties of the same name "_xmlns_content"
>               this problem is related to the following location: RssRoot

What else can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be better to use existing libraries for RSS support (such as [ROME](https://rome.dev.java.net/)) instead of creating your own.

But if you actually want:

- `xmlns:content` is not an attribute, it's a namespace declaration. JAXB adds it to the resulting XML automatically when resulting XML contains elements in that namespace (namespace of elements can be specified using `namespace` attribute in `@XmlElement`, `@XmlRootElement`, etc).
- To rename `rssRoot` to `rss`, write `@XmlRootElement(name = "rss")`.